# printing a shell script in coulor righting in gedit

Tags: shell, printing, gedit

I done a shell script in gedit and it has a different colours for each type of writing , declaring functions, echo statements ect, however , how do i print and print the colours. - On paper

Thanks all

Comment: You want to print the script with colors on paper or you want to output text from the shell script to the screen in color?

Comment: print to the printer on paper in colour. Its already on the screen in colour

Comment: Does simply telling gedit to print the document not do that?

Comment: no , that what i would have thought.set to rgb colour , dont know why
. And yes , it is a colour printer:L

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: http://blog.vinceliu.com/2008/06/printing-syntax-highlighted-source-code.html

It should allow you to print syntax highlighting.